# Spring boot actuator for tomcat executor service info

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Does spring boot actuator metrics endpoint give information on tomcat executor service threads ? I would like to know how many threads out of default 200 exposed by tomcat for incoming requests are consumed already.
I can do this by adding Pom dependency for tools like javaMelody and check maxThreads
Wondering if actuator gives this info out of the box